# Induction-heating-circuit doesn't draw any current

Tags: power-electronics, induction, troubleshooting

I've tried to build an induction-heating-circuit, but it doesn't draw any current from my adjustable transformer, no matter which voltage I give it. I planned to run it from mains-voltage (230V-50Hz). The inductance of my work-coil is around 100 µH, the work-cap is around 330 nF which gives me a resonant frequency of 28.5 kHz. I adjusted my driver-IC to output me this, and it works great. But my adjustable transformer just shows me 0 A current. I am sure that this measurement is right, because the IGBTs also don't get hot. Please help me[image: Circuit]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What waveforms do you see on HO and LO on your driver?

Comment: it looks like one output is broken. Now im trying to change my circuit to half bridge. Do you know if the IC is able to drive a half bridge?

Comment: Probably yes. Which output is broken? Please be aware that number one killer of MOSFET drivers is poor layout forcing COM below 0 V locally.

Comment: People are voting to close this question. PLEASEV provide enough details for us to reasonably understand the question. Any informatuin you have that we don't know, wh should know.